# Is there any benefit to spammers oversaturating a service?

Tags: spam

If I understand correctly, spam is most effective when it looks like real content and entices a user to do whatever the spam is asking it to (for example, clicking on a link.) Naturally, keeping a low profile would be essential to hiding it from the prying eyes of moderators.

However, what I've noticed in practice is the opposite. Spammers will use as many resources as possible and attack websites relentlessly, to the point where the service is no longer usable. With no real users to be tricked and the spam being so blatant that it can't possibly trick anyone, why would they waste resources doing this?

I understand the shotgun approach in which random websites will get hit by spammers. But I've noticed on certain websites, like chat websites, that the spam is targeted specifically towards that website.

How does oversaturating a website possibly benefit a spammer unless their intent was to make the website unusable for others?

Answer (score 1):

Spammers' cost per spam is incredibly low, and sadly, they do get click throughs. The percentage of them is also low, so the single best approach a spammer can take is to, well, spam as much as they can.

It doesn't have to fool humans, as enough will click on it that it wins for the spammer.

Answer (score 1):

> Spammers will use as many resources as possible and attack websites relentlessly, to the point where the service is no longer usable. With no real users to be tricked and the spam being so blatant that it can't possibly trick anyone, why would they waste resources doing this?

There are a couple of reasons why websites will get massive amounts of spam attacks. More than likely, it's because there are *a lot* of spammers. There are many, many companies out there dedicated to creating illegal spam bots and flooding the web. Many of them just happen bombard the same place.

If it is a sudden, out-of-nowhere spike in traffic that crashes the service than it could be an attempted attack to gain access to the system, or it could be a DDoS attack. This means someone or some organization is trying to compromise the system, rather than utilize it for promotional purpose.

Answer (score 0):

They might be trying to increase the search ranking of a site or something else - as far as I understand search engine rankings, the more places that link to something, the higher it's ranked. The higher a dodgy site is ranked, the more likely potential victims are to click on it when searching.